# PHP script creates XML files from CSV's but holds 0 contents

Tags: php, xml, csv, fgets, fgetcsv

I have created a php script to read through 19 csv files and normalises the data - not holding repeating data (station id, name & geocode) and only holding the attributes for each record which have values. I have printed the csv's to make sure the are loading within the script and the script also makes the data-*site-id* files but contains 0 contents within the file?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// List of CSV files
$csvFiles = [
    'data-203.csv',
    'data-206.csv',
    'data-209.csv',
    'data-270.csv',
    'data-213.csv',
    'data-215.csv',
    'data-271.csv',
    'data-375.csv',
    'data-395.csv',
    'data-447.csv',
    'data-452.csv',
    'data-463.csv',
    'data-500.csv',
    'data-501.csv',
    'data-672.csv',
    'data-188.csv',
    'data-209.csv',
    'data-481.csv',
    'data-228.csv',
    'data-459.csv',

];

// Loop through each CSV file
foreach ($csvFiles as $csvFile) {
    $csvFilePath = __DIR__ . '/' . $csvFile;
    
    // Open the CSV file
    if (($handle = fopen($csvFilePath, 'r')) !== false) {
        // Create an XMLWriter instance
        $xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
        $xmlWriter->openURI(csvFileToXmlFile($csvFile));
        $xmlWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $xmlWriter->startElement('data');

        // Read the CSV file line by line
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
            // Skip empty lines
            if (count($data) === 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // Ensure the array has the necessary indexes
            if (count($data) >= 4) {
                // Extract the necessary data
                $stationId = $data[0];
                $name = $data[1];
                $geocode = $data[2];
                $attribute = $data[3];

                // Check if the attribute has a value
                if (trim($attribute) !== '') {
                    // Start XML record element
                    $xmlWriter->startElement('record');
                    $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('station_id', $stationId);
                    $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('name', $name);
                    $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('geocode', $geocode);
                    $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('attribute', $attribute);
                    // End XML record element
                    $xmlWriter->endElement();
                }
            }
        }

        // Close XML elements and file
        $xmlWriter->endElement();
        $xmlWriter->endDocument();
        $xmlWriter->flush();
        fclose($handle);

        // Output success message
        $xmlFile = csvFileToXmlFile($csvFile);
        echo "XML file generated successfully: $xmlFile\n";
    }
}

// Function to convert CSV file name to XML file name
function csvFileToXmlFile($csvFile) {
    $fileParts = pathinfo($csvFile);
    $xmlFile = $fileParts['filename'] . '.xml';
    return $xmlFile;
}

?>
```

As mentioned, I have printed the csv's to make sure they are being read within the directory. I also changed the $xmlWriter->openURI($csvFileToXmlFile($csvFile)); to $xmlWriter->openURI(csvFileToXmlFile($csvFile));. I have been getting Undefined offset 2 & 3. Line 52 & 53 error before hand too, these have subsided.

Sample image of csv, wasn't sure how to send it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EUHN4RCJFq-XrIBQNvZphh7vxZDdbf_R/view?usp=share_link

Blank XML - data-481.xml
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pEinOeosPQQRoeQoJHfEb6L_80iD5bqr/view?usp=share_link

[desired XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFTt5.png)

Comment: Can you show a sample of one of the csv files (data-203.csv will do).

Comment: have attached at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must learn to look closely at your data. The `csv` files are in fact `ssv` files "SemiColon seperated value" files

All you need to do is change this line of code to let `fgetcsv()` know the seperator is a `;`

```
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,10000,';')) !== false) {
```

Second Issue with data-481.csv

the `$data[1], $data[2], $data[3]` columns are all empty for all lines

So

```
$attribute = $data[3];
if (trim($attribute) !== '') {
```

which controls whether the row gets written to the xml file fails, so no data is written

Comment: Hi there, could you have a look at the answer on my previous question as this was the output data as advised, which were stated to be csv

Comment: Its got an extension of `.csv` but the seperator is in fact a `;`

Comment: this has worked by data-481.xml is empty

Comment: Well probably the 481 input file is in some way different. Show me that file, or look yourself

Comment: what would cause this as it's produced 18 files the exact same but this file different, I've opened it in numbers and it seems the same

Comment: Thats a picture, thats no use to me

Comment: even tho the csv has content? very strange, very stuck now

Comment: see answer for reason

Comment: I see, makes sense but confused to why within the shared link it has entries filled but these don't convey into the readability within the script?

Comment: You showed a pic of the blank colums?

Comment: that was from original, I've updated with a link with the entire csv with data-481 tagged, may have missed it

Comment: No i looked at each line and they all have a blank column in $data[3] therefore no data written

Comment: because [3] none is written at all, I am now following, I thought it would miss this column and carry on

Comment: Which is what if (trim($attribute) !== '') { fixes?

Comment: Also, it seems that the XML file isn't following the same format as exampled within the new image added

Comment: Well thats because you are picking data from the wrong columns. And creating the XML in a completely different way. Are all these files in the same format? Or is this one different to all the others